# URL of repository on Git

Tags: git, url, github

When I see other's git repositories, There is a link to open the file on browser.
And here's the question:

After I commit my project on my Git, How can I get that kind of URL?

So other people can see my project on the browser directly.

Answer (score 2):

> After I commit my project on my Git

That a *local* operation done on your workstation: there is no "public" URL for other to browse to.

You need to *push* ([`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)) to a [public GitHub repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/pushing-commits-to-a-remote-repository) in order for others to be able to see your work.

Answer (score 0):

The URL of your project repository will be same all the time. Only you can vary it by commit IDs.

By default, if you share the repo URL, it will show the latest commited codes on your REPO. So other people can easily able to see your latest changes.

Hope this will clarify you. Cheers!